# mach-o linker error when trying to use ASIHTTP

Tags: ios, objective-c, compiler-errors, linker, asihttprequest

I'm trying to use ASIHTTP in my app.
I had some probelms importing and linking everything right, but I found all the answers here except one.
I get a "Apple mach-o linker error" for many items, all referenced from a **ASIWebPageRequest** class methods in a file called  "ASIWebPageRequest.o".
I don't really know where to find this file and how to fix this issue,
Anyone has a clue?

Thanks,
Yonathan

Edit - Fixed it by adding libxml2.dylib to my project, for some reason it is not included in http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions. I just compared the frameworks included in ASIHTTPRequest demo projects to mine and found out it was missing.

Comment: Since you seem to have fixed it, you could post that as the answer. As an aside, you might better off staying away from `ASIHttpRequest` since it is no longer maintained. [AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.com/) is a popular alternative.

Comment: Thanks mike, I'll check it out.
I tried to post it as an answer but i had to wait 8 hours since I don't have enough credits :) so I'm doing it now.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding libxml2.dylib to my project, for some reason it is not included in http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions. I just compared the frameworks included in ASIHTTPRequest demo projects to mine and found out it was missing.